# How is this type of job described in English? science/scientific advisor/counselor?

Tags: phrase-request, nouns, adjective-phrases

I am a Spanish speaker and I need to set what I am in English.

My clients are dentists. They come to me when they are in the last year of their university (grade, master, etc.). I help them to do their thesis, sometimes I do all the work, sometimes I just help them to do it, and sometimes I tell them how to do it. Some dentists come to me looking for this service, but instead of thesis, they need to publish papers in scientific journals.

So, am I a Science advisor or a scientific advisor?

Comment: I would say *advisor* or *consultant*. In some respects, such as helping students learn, you could use *tutor*. The problem with your question is that the field of occupations that you are trying to describe is too broad to pick just one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a student asks someone else to write an academic paper for them, that's considered a form of [plagiarism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plagiarism) and is often grounds for expulsion.  This is the reason for Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment about "criminal conspiracy".

However if they come to you as an *research assistant* to help them find sources, refine topics, etc., then that's fine.  It's also fine if they write the paper and come to you as an *editor* to help clean up the text.

(To be clear, this applies mostly to *students* who are held to certain academic standards.  Professional academics and doctors may hire someone to do most of the actual *work* while they provide supervision and oversight.)

As mentioned, the generic term for this is *consultant*.  Specifically you can call yourself a *scientific consultant*, *scientific researcher*, or *scientific editor*.  *Academic* also works, if you provide services over a range of academic fields.

Something like *research assistant* is also good, since it clarifies you only *support* their work, and you're not doing all the work for them.

Comment: Thanks! And how different would be "science advisor" from "scientific advisor"??